# Flutter: Updated a plugin in resulted in an error about a deprecated API

Tags: flutter, plugins, parameters, deprecated

My original error was this:

```
      theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:106:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.4/lib/src/selectDialog.dart:153:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'child'.
      child: AlertDialog(
      ^^^^^
/D:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart:1065:12: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<T?> showDialog<T>({
           ^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1029

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        15.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Once I changed the plugin in my pubspec.yaml I ended up getting this:

```
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\apple_sign_in-0.1.0\android\src\main\java\dev\gilder\tom\apple_sign_in\AppleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated 
API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.5.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.14.1+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.18.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-4.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:47: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_keyboard_visibility-3.2.2\android\src\main\java\com\jrai\flutter_keyboard_visibility\FlutterKeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Program Files\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.5.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Parameter format not correct -
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       136.8s
Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under D:\WEBDEV\Endev Studios\Medical App\Brian's Dev Work at GSH\APP
TESTING\skinopathy-doctors\build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

I'm using Flutter and I'm on the Master channel.

I've done:

flutter clean

flutter upgrade

flutter pub get

I don't even understand why I would have to go into the pubspec.yaml file to make changes; I thought flutter upgrade and flutter pub get dealt with all that.

The strange thing is, no one else seems to be getting this error but me.  A thing to note: I am using VS Code and my colleagues are using intelliJ.  They are able to access a "Flutter Plugins" folder and actually bring up a file for the plugin and make changes to resolve this.  I don't have a Flutter Plugins folder.

Thank you in advance to everyone who helps.

Comment: Have you try creating a new app, put the dependencies (with the same version) in and try to run it. Please try and let me know the output since this might be some versioning error, or might be a local sdk error

Comment: Sadly no.  Truth is, I'm still a little new to the Flutter scene and I'm doing the maintenance for this app (it's for a company).

Here is the absolutely silly thing: I changed a dependency (which wasn't even that much) and ran it on an emulator.  It crashed.

Then I just changed it back and ran it on my phone and now it works.  I do NOT know why.  If ANYONE can explain this please do.  It's not just the solution I was looking for, it was the process and reason why it was broken/why it works.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it related to some native features?

Comment: This app is using a bunch of plugins but the one I tinkered with was: dropdown_search: ^0.4.4